# What should we do about excessive content "seeding"?

Tags: discussion, seeding-questions, abuse

I want to believe the user is genuinely trying to generate content.

However, I don't like it.

What does everybody else think?

[image]

Comment: I made a more general question about the same topic: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42/what-to-do-with-class-based-questions

Comment: Holy cow that's a lot of questions with just one word difference.

Comment: @random and that one word happens to make how the game is played totally different. "use skill x when y happens" is a _bad_ answer if you're looking for an answer for a class that doesn't have skill x.

Comment: @random and I don't disagree its a lot of questions with one word difference.

Comment: broken picture link

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems spammy to create all of them like that, and I'm having trouble seeing how the answer will be the "one definitive correct answer on the Internet" -- they seem more likely to be subjective and constantly changing.  I think they should be closed.

Comment: Especially if they're looking for links to other guides, it could be summed up with a definitive "Class Guides" question.

Comment: I disagree @David, these question ARE valid. It's just that the way they are being asked right now, doesn't qualify them as real, expert questions

Comment: I agree with @Ivo the questions should be formulated as "What are the best references sites about [subject]" I think

Comment: Or the question more specific about the answered required :  A guide to what ? Levelling easily, questing fast, doing raids ? Do you want theory crafting, guide lines, forum links ?

Comment: I would want a mashup @MarmouCorp Look at ElitistJerks, they have so much info spread over even more posts. We need some distilled compendiums of that kind of info with links to more if your interested

Comment: So far I've been voting to close them as a duplicate of the 'World of Warcraft Guides' question he asked. Same goes for his LotRO questions. It seems to me that one question to rule them all is better than 20 on the same subject.

Comment: I concur with @Ivo's comment and @Revoked's answer http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30/what-should-we-do-about-excessive-content-seeding/47#47

Answer (score 5):

These seem to be answers looking for a question. This site, however, is about questions looking for answer.

Comment: that doesn't fit with most of them not having answers, does it?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think gaming.stackexchange.com should be a place where you can find an answer as to how to level X class of Y game in the most efficient manner.

IMO:

Downvoting/Banning/Deleting these types of questions now only serves the purpose to get it out of your face when there are only ~100 questions on the site (admittedly annoying). But I think that eventually these questions are going to be allowed and answered.

Comment: I agree with you in principle, but to have one person running around a dropping 20 WoW leveling questions in 20 minutes, is detrimental to the site.  It is little more than spam.  I think the larger issue here could be solved with a little throttling.

Comment: +1 for the throttling @tzenes, I'm sure he doesn't intend to spam, he's just a little enthusiastic. With some throttling, it's no problem

Comment: +1 for throttling then.  I liked the idea of only being "allowed" to ask questions for a class you're actively leveling, but the moderating function seems impossible on that. IMO: maybe just tell this guy directly to cool it and let someone else ask the question since this is beta and we're all supposed to be working together?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'm amazed at the number of down-votes and closes going on over things like this. You can't say that you're attempting to build out tons of content in beta so that it's ready for live and then knock people for trying to fill out the common questions.

Sure, I think it's probably some rep-whoring, but over all I think it's an attempt to fill that void.

Oh, and take a moment to look through the reasons for down-votes and closes - they're pretty much all SnA. C'mon guys, you're trying to build a "gaming community" with 99% of the people being developers (you know you're all here from SO, don't lie). Loosen up a little, when real gamers are involved it has to have a little subjectivity - we're not talking about (most of) our professions here; just our pastimes.

Do you want a gaming Q/A site, or SO: Gaming Edition?

Comment: I agree to that but the "warrior guide" is too generic. The only less generic question (levelling guide) has been answered. A guide to what ? Levelling easily, questing fast, doing raids ? Do you want theory crafting, guide lines, forum links ?

Comment: No, the site should not be seeded with this questions right off the bat. If these will be asked naturally, why not let them be asked naturally when someone's actually interested in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure his intent is not to rep whore (though especially the WoW one will gather lot's of rep if not CW)

However, users should be interested in their question and actually care if they get an answer. So no, in this sense this is unwanted behavior.

But that doesn't make his questions less viable!

Comment: I've moved away from the WoW ones and am working on the LOTR:O one's to help mitigate this perception.

Answer (score 1):

I know it looks spammy right now, but keep in mind that we're seeding the site with questions.  A lot of that will look like rep-whoring.  These should, though, be community wiki.