# What to do with class based questions?

Tags: discussion, seeding-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should we do about excessive content “seeding”?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30/what-should-we-do-about-excessive-content-seeding)

Currently there's a bunch of questions on classes for LOTR:O and WoW

Now I truly believe there is valuable information for each separate class, like class specific blogs or other resources.

However, in the beginning of the site I feel that posting 10 question on the same game is seeding the site in a bad way. Remember, we should be **asking real, expert questions**.

So for as long as the private beta goes, I would prefer to see users only asking these questions for the class **they themselves** play, rather than for every class out there. Perhaps someone else will want to ask it for his own class too, but at least it's a legitimate question and the user will want to hear answers, rather than abandoning them.

I would vote against closing them, but no new seeds should be allowed for now.

Any opinions on what to do?

Comment: I'm ok with that.

Comment: I know and I hope they don't close your questions as I do think classes really are different

Comment: I'm definitely taking a rep hit on those questions, and I think it's targeted against me, but w/e. The community will win in the end.

Comment: Can a single question be composed to cover all the classes per game?

Comment: @antony.trupe - I was not one of the downvoters (though I did vote to close a couple of them) but the problem is that all of the questions are so general that the answers really won't vary much.  Add to that the perception that you "spammed" all of the questions in a very short period of time with only minor variations, and I think a few people were kind of upset about that.

Comment: @Galactic I don't deny it appeared spammy, at best. I started with the classes I play(ed), then extrapolated that other people play other classes and would ask about those classes, and thought it would be nice if there was already a question with answers for them to find instead of having to start from the beginning. Perhaps the right approach would have been to broaden the topic of a single question, perhaps not.

Comment: @antony.trupe I think each class deserves it's own post. If you want to describe each tree only, you already need 3 answers. Which would lead to 24 answers, just to describe all the classes. It would be undo-able

Comment: @Ivo for the sake of getting-along(and my own rep) I deleted the ones that were heavily down-voted.

Comment: I agree with Juan, one question to rule them all will be much better than 20. Most guides that will be linked to will have class-specific chapters. This only leads to a lot of questions with none/dissatisfactory answers, which won't help a new user much.

Answer (score -2):

For WoW, each class will probably need 3 questions: one for each tree.
I concede that the rate may have been excessive; the ones that were heavily down-voted have been deleted.