# Detail of Guide Answers

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we Link to Content or Contain content?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127/should-we-link-to-content-or-contain-content)

Since this is a gaming website, there will be a lot of answers linking to online guides. Would it be better to just post the link to the guide, or posting the article in the answer if it's short?

For example, I posted the whole article [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/865/how-to-get-the-guardin-gnome-achievement-in-left-4-dead-2/). Would it be better if I just had the link like I did [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/629/replace-nes-battery/)? (Then again, the article there is extremely long.)

Comment: I had no idea how to title this question . . .

Comment: Perhaps something more like here? http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127/should-we-link-to-content-or-contain-content

Comment: I provided my answer on the other question

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice that question. Voting to close my own question. (lol?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's best to link the article **and** provide a summary in your own words. That way it's not direct plagiarism, but the summary does give some added value and saves some time for the readers if they are not interested in more details.