# Kickstarting this site in existing community

Tags: discussion

I've created a few questions about a game I play in, in the hope to kick start its community to use and appreciate this website. I'm unsure about whether my attempt will succeed, but I had to try.

Is it okay to do so, however? It feels a bit like [content farming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42/what-to-do-with-class-based-questions)...

Comment: Provide links to the questions, maybe?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1643/how-many-ab1-missiles-should-i-bring-along-to-stealth-bomb-an-ic-garrison, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1644/is-ship-turn-rate-still-limited-by-the-viewport-what-ships-turn-faster-if-you, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/when-is-it-appropriate-to-buy-gunships-as-bios, and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1678/whats-the-order-ships-should-go-through-an-aleph-when-bomb-running. Alternatively, just check the profile at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/23/badp#qpage_1-apage_1-qsort_newest-asort_votes

Comment: If all else fails, I'll get tumbleweed :D

Comment: What genre does Allegience fall under, as a whole? I'm not talking what elements of different genres it might exhibit in different parts of the game, but does it classify as a real-time-strategy game, or is it a game of another genre that has real-time-strategy elements at certain parts? What do you say?

Comment: @Grace If you're the comm it's an RTS. If you're a pilot it's a 3D space sim.

Comment: ...pwa, I was afraid of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, you should ask questions only in one of these two cases:

1. You're actually interested in the answer
2. You already know a great answer

I think that as long as the questions themselves are concrete and you fulfill one of the two conditions above, it's perfectly fine, even if it feels spammy. What I would not like to see are either a bunch of questions which are themselves not 100% okay (such as in the link you provided), or a bunch of questions that will remain unanswered and you don't really care about.

Comment: +1 specially for number 1. Ask what you want to know! Can't go wrong there (as long as it's on topic ;) )

Comment: Re: 1. I think I have :) I didn't exactly ask easy questions. We have a wiki for the easy stuff; this site is for _expert_ Q&A. (Except for [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1678/whats-the-order-ships-should-go-through-an-aleph-when-bomb-running), for which I had instead an adequate answer.)